# Android HttpPost not sending post data

Tags: php, android, http, post

I have found lots of information online but cannot get my android app to send Post data, it is connecting to the php files on my server but my server is not receiving the $_POST['task'].

Here is my applications connection code, where params is a 3 part name value list:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
httpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

and a cutdown version of my index.php file :

```
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] != ''){

$task = $_POST['task'];
$response = array("task" => $task, "success" => 0, "error"=> 0);

require_once 'include/handler.php';
$db_handler = new Handler();

//log in, check user details.
  if($task == 'login'){
    //do some stuff to check login      
  }else {
      $response["error"] = 1;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect TASK";
      echo json_encode($response);
  } 

}else{
    $response["error"] = 1;
    $response["error_msg"] = "TASK NOT PRESENT";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

It only ever replies with the end else not with any other information. Any help would be much appreciated, the tutorial I have been using in my research is here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: You haven't shown your params.

Comment: Params is a NameValuePair list of 3 elements, one of which is task. Sorry if that was not clear enough.

Comment: @BenAshwell post complete php code it is missing some `if/else` statement

Comment: @BenAshwell try to download  apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and use it to make the post , one of my colleagues ran into this issue before , let me know if it works

Comment: This tutorial is crappy, because he is making the NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: I have removed the bit in the if else that may be confusing it was just to check about the login details, this section is not running anyway.

Comment: Do you have any others that I could look at that are better, its just some reaserch I am doing so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Please please make all network Traffic in a AsyncTask!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> has been set?

Comment: Yeah it has sorry, should have said that above.

Comment: @BenAshwell make sure you get data `var_dump($_POST)`, it could be so many things, you have to narrow down the issue yourself